# SAP UI5 issue, render Calling two time in Custom Control

Tags: sapui5

In view

```
var oData = {
        "SavedSearch" : [
            {   name : "Save1" },
            {   name : "Save2" },
            {   name : "Save3" },
            {   name : "Save4" },
            {   name : "Save5" }
        ]
    }
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(oData);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"ModelData");
    var oTest = new test({
        manageSavedSearch :{
                path    : "ModelData>/SavedSearch",
                template: new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    text : "{ModelData>name}"
                })
        },
    });
    oTest.placeAt(this);
```

In Custom Control

```
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("test",{
metadata:{
    properties : {},
    aggregations:{      
        manageSavedSearch   :   {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple :true },
        layout              :   {type : "sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout", multiple :false }
    }
},
init : function(){
},
renderer : {
    render : function(oRm, oControl) {
  // Come two Times  Here
        var manageSavedSearch = oControl.getManageSavedSearch();
        var oSavedButtonHLyt = new sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout();
        for(var index = 0 ; index < manageSavedSearch.length ; index++){
            oSavedButtonHLyt.addContent(manageSavedSearch[index]);
        }
        oControl.setAggregation("layout",oSavedButtonHLyt);
       oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("layout"));
    }
  }
},
onAfterRendering: function(){}
});
```

If I don't use any layout then It doesn't come two time in render otherwise it comes two time in render. This issues is happening from `version 1.24.4`. please Can I have any guidance here.

Comment: It's good that you've added the code, but can you explain briefly what exactly you are trying to achieve and also the error/unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @Breakpoint - It is coming two time in render, whenever I use any Layout controls from `version 1.24.4`. It is just simple example. My question is why it is coming two times. And how I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing aggregation(e.g. add/remove/insert/set/removeAll) invalidates the control. You should never invalidate a control during the rendering. In your case it can be an infinite loop.

To debug rendering invalidation there is a url parameter test.html?sap-ui-xx-debugRendering=true then you can see the rendering stack trace and who is responsible for the rendering.

In your code sample, there are two aggregations update. setAggregation and addContent.
Aggregation mutatators uses 3rd parameter to suppress invalidation. So following will insert the aggregation but suppress the invalidation since whole control will be rendered at the end it will not be a problem.

```
oControl.setAggregation("layout",oSavedButtonHLyt, true); // suppress invalidate
```

I guess you assume same should work for addContent

```
oSavedButtonHLyt.addAggregation("content", manageSavedSearch[index], true);
```

But it does not because here manageSavedSearch[index], so your template clone's parent is oTest initially, but you are changing the parent with addAggregation because layout will be the parent. But UI5 cannot determine automatically for the previous parent's suppress since its aggregation will be moved to somewhere else. So we go with

```
oControl.removeAggregation("manageSavedSearch", manageSavedSearch[index], true);
oSavedButtonHLyt.addAggregation("content", manageSavedSearch[index], true);
```

Here is the jsbin http://jsbin.com/rezayebada/1/edit?js,output

BTW, as you mentioned this is just an example **do not take this as a reference for building composite controls.**

Basically, property/aggregation/association changes invalidates the control if the control does not overwrite its mutator methods. I see it is not easy to understand what invalidates when but sap-ui-xx-debugRendering=true helps you to understand with stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but even If we are setting aggregation in `init` method it has effect and it works same (coming two times in render) and layout aggregation's multiple is `false`.

Comment: sure setAggregation invalidates on init as well but the point not to invalidate a control during the rendering is protecting infinite rendering<->invalidation loops. set/add/remove/insertAggregation has a 3rd boolean parameter to suppress invalidate. But you should use the generated layout for the next rendering. Also it seems like layout could be an hidden aggregation. Actually you do not need layout as an aggregation you can keep it as a local reference since it has nothing to do with binding propagation.

Comment: It is just example. My question is why it is coming two times. And how I can solve this issue.

Comment: I already explained. You should not invalidate a control during the rendering. Probably jsbin will help more to explain so see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem I was also facing, you can do one thing try using local resources
 rather than online resources.

Comment: I am using local resources which is upgraded to `version 1.24.4`